# Python mock transaction request

Tags: python, transactions, mocking, functional-testing

I am trying to functional test my code which writes data to a data store and everything is wrapped in a transaction request in order to make the write operations atomic.

```
def xyz(self, list):

        txn = self._client.transaction()
        for temp in list:
            path = '/a/b/c/{}'.format(temp)
            self.set_data(txn, path, '')
        self.commit_transaction(txn)
```

To functional test my code, I can pass in test cases for the list parameter and using fake client and fakefilesystem to write to the data store but while trying to fake the transaction request like this -

```
obj._client = fake_client.FakeClient()
txn = obj._client.transaction()
        txn.client = obj._client
```

where obj is the instance of the class to which xyz() belongs.

This results in a fake transaction request attribute error -

```
AttributeError: 'FakeTransactionRequest' object has no attribute 'client'
```

Any ideas how can I mock this transaction (txn) object ?

Comment: Which line generates that error? Sounds like `FakeClient` is too fake.

Comment: self.set_data(txn, path, '') . This generates the FakeTransaction request error.